# Vertically aligning an image in a div element?

Tags: css

I have a div element whose height I set with `em`, and whose width I set as a percentage. There is an image contained within. It has a width as a percentage (83%). However, if I am at a resolution where that div element is starting to get a little narrow, the image narrows up as well, but rather than taking up the entire div (as it should), the image just becomes small and appears just at the top of the div. To compensate for this, I want to vertically align my image within the div element. How can I do this?

Comment: What is your codding language ? is it pure html or Asp.net or PHP ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

vertical-align does not work in `DIV` elements. the only way to do this is to set this property to your div in css :

```
.divClass
{
   display:table-cell;
   vertical-align:middle;
}
```

after it, your `DIV` element will act like `TD` elemnt of Table.

to align your image in div with specifying percentage for image vertical position look at link bellow (percentage value) :

http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/vertical-align

Comment: Setting `display: table-cell;` made my div element behave very oddly (it got very big, much bigger than it should be). I already have `display: inline-block;` set on that div.

Comment: There is no other way. you have two options. you can set display to table-cell and correct sizing problems or manage your image position using javascript (with margin and padding) in javascript on load (not recommended)

Comment: No one is using IE6 now! and number of IE7 users are going down very fast. The most users are now using IE8 IE9 FireFox, Chrome, Safari and ...

Comment: @Farzin IE6 and IE7 are still considered by some clients though.

Comment: @Farzin plenty of people still use IE6. Each website owner/company must weigh up the percentage of users on outdated browsers and whether it wants to keep supporting them verses the potential loss of business if those browsers will no longer be able to view the site effectively. In those situations [progressive enhancement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Progressive_enhancement) should be encouraged. In practice though, a lot of companies still unfortunately subscribe to the "it must look the same in all browsers - including IE6" idea. Education is our weapon!

Answer (score 0):

Give the div `position:absolute` and the image inside it `position:relative` with `top:50%` and margin top equals to negative half the image height. This will center your image vertically.

```
div{
    border:1px solid red;
    width:400px;
    height:400px;
    position:relative;
}

img{
    position:absolute;
    top:50%;
    margin-top:-64px; /*negative half image height */
}
```

### Check working example at http://jsfiddle.net/qtL4n/

Comment: Come on... Stop setting negative margin! its really a wrong and anti-pattern!

Comment: @farzin, this technique has been used since CSS came out. No need to  re-invent the wheel. This is one of the great and effective uses of negative margin. Calling it wrong is very broad. It only makes it wrong if misused just like everything else.