# How do I use CSS to to vertically center align an image in a div?

Tags: css

I have the following

[image]

and want to vertically center-align the image.

How would I do this?

thx

Comment: possible duplicate of [Vertically aligning an image in a div element?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5644737/vertically-aligning-an-image-in-a-div-element)

Comment: Possible Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7273338/how-to-properly-vertically-align-an-image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't in divs by default (with straight css anyway). You have to set the containing div as a table-cell and vertical align it middle like so:

```
.ios-image-box
{
   display: table-cell;
   vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Comment: is it possible to do it not as a `display: table-cell`?

Comment: cool, stumbled across this too http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3655331/css-vertically-center-an-image-within-a-floated-div which also gave more info. this seems to work. thx

Comment: Yeah, the only way I know to do it without JavaScript is through `display: table-cell;`. I know that it seems kind of hacky, but it seems to be the preferred way to do it.